# i have checked all the indentations and i think everything is all good but my script is returning this error from my index.tsx file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have checked all the indentations and I think everything is all good but my script is returning this error from my `index.tsx` file:

```js
./pages/index.tsx:153:7
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

  151 | };
  152 | 
> 153 | export getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
      |        ^
  154 |   const categories = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mt/categories?`);
  155 |   return ({
  156 |       categoryOptions: await categories.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `const` declaration for `getServerSideProps`:

`export getServerSideProps`

should by

`export const getServerSideProps`

Comment: i just did that and it came down with this Error: Additional keys were returned from `getServerSideProps`. Properties intended for your component must be nested under the `props` key, e.g.:

 return { props: { title: 'My Title', content: '...' } }

Keys that need to be moved: categoryOptions.

Comment: Check docs about `getServerSideProps` https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering Basically error says it all, you need to return object with `props` key, like that `return { props: { categoryOptions: { ... } } }`